# How to do a quick inline method with conditional?

Tags: c#, methods, conditional-statements, inline-method

This is what I'd like to do:

```
string x = if(true) "String Val" else "No String Val";
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Probably not a valid answer to this question (hence a comment instead): if your condition is a null check, e.g. `string x = (s != null) ? s : "Something else"`, you can do `string x = s ?? "Something else"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're talking about is called a conditional statement:

```
string x = boolVal ? "String Val" : "No String Val";
```

If you really want the string to have no value if the bool is false, you could change to:

```
string x = boolVal ? "String Val" : null;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string x = condition ? trueValue : falseValue;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

Comment: Just to clarify: those values can actually be any expression. They must both be strings though, or in the general case, they must be of the same type.